# Sending an SMS via IBM WebMQ from VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ibm-mq

My company has an IBM WebMQ license / server installed.  They have set up a queue for me to use.  I have set up a environment variable which seems to be working.  I have installed the free WebMQ client and registered the MQAX200.dll file.

I have searched high and low for VBScript code to send messages but all I can find is to list received messaged.

```
Set MQSess = CreateObject( "MQAX200.MQSession" )
Set QMgr = MQSess.AccessQueueManager( QueueMgrName )
```

This code sets up the connection and accesses the queue I need to use to send the SMS.  Any idea on how to actually send the SMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good CodeProject resource to check out, this project has a full class demonstrating the usage.
Also note that the linked project is in C#, but the underlying objects are used the same way one you have a valid instance of the object.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14009/Interfacing-with-IBM-WebSphere-MQ-formally-IBM-MQS

Comment: @user3017424 take a look at my answer to "[Add Server Details to connect to IBM Websphere MQ series in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477111/add-server-details-to-connect-to-ibm-websphere-mq-series-in-vb6/42498329#42498329)", Summary, MQAX (MQ ActiveX) support was stabilized at MQ v6 level and in MQ v9 it has been deprecated. In summary it has been stabilized and has not been enhanced since IBM MQ v6.0 released in June 2005 and has only had defect fixes. In v9.0 it has been deprecated which indicates that IBM will remove it from a future release of the product.

Comment: @user3017424 IBM states "IBM MQ Classes for .NET are the recommended replacement technology."